# Capture name of function while matching whole function

Tags: javascript, regex, node.js

This regex

```
/function\s*\(\s*\S*\s*\)\s*\{/
```

should match a single parameter function, something like

```
function foo ( xyz ) {
```

(note that "\S" will match any non-whitespace character, and we can assume the original code is correct in using acceptable chars, so it's ok)

my question is, how can I match a line of text like so

> "baz function foo ( xyz ) { bar"

and capture both this:

```
"function foo ( xyz ) {"
```

and

```
"foo"
```

In other words, I'd like to somehow match the beginning of the function signature, as well as capture the name of the function.

I am not sure how to do this.

The "easy" way would be to do something like:

```
var match = str.match(regex);  // "function foo ( xyz ) {"

var start = 7;  // "function" has two 'n's unfortunately
var end= match[0].indexOf('(');

var result = String(match[0]).substring(start,end).trim();
```

But I am looking for perhaps a less hacky way.

Answer (score 1):

You can capture the function signature and function name using capturing groups like this.

**Regex:** `function\s+([^(]+)\s*\(\s*[^)]+\s*\)\s*{`

**Explanation:**

- `function\s+` matches the keyword `function` marking the beginning of function.
- `([^(]+)` matches and captures name of function in 1st groups. Could be back referenced using `\1` or `$1`.
- `\s*\(\s*[^)]+\s*\)\s*{` matches rest till an opening curly brace `{` is met.

**[Regex101 Demo](https://regex101.com/r/fB5eA9/1)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following:

```
(function\s*(\S+)?\s*\(\s*\S+\s*\)\s*\{)
```

See [RegEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/xH8kK5/3)

Capture group 1 will contain `function foo ( xyz ) {` and capture group 2 will contain `foo`

**Edit:** Updated for anonymous functions

Comment: thanks, I tried it, I don't think it matches this line of code " after(function (d) {", any idea why?

Comment: @AlexMills: Because it's an anonymous function with **no name**.

Comment: crap, I should have stipulated this, could you make it work if there is no name?

Comment: I guess just change it from (\S+) to  (\S*) ?

Comment: huh, is there an advantage of this "(\S+)?" over (\S*) ?

Comment: @AlexMills In case of anonymous functions, `(\S*)` will capture empty string in 2nd group wheras `(\S+)?` will capture nothing :)

Answer (score 1):

try this

```
(function\s+([^\(\s]+).*?\)\s*\{)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZ2sL7/1)**

```js
var myval = "baz function foo ( xyz ) { bar";
var regex = /(function\s+([^\(\s]+).*?\)\s*\{)/mg
while (matches = regex.exec(myval)) {
    document.writeln(matches[1]) //function definition
    document.writeln(matches[2]) //function name
}
```

**UPDATE** for *anonymous functions*

check this

```
(function(\s+([^\(\s]+))?.*?\)\s*\{)
```

**[Regex Demo](https://regex101.com/r/iZ2sL7/2)**

```js
var myval = "function ( abc ) {";
var regex = /(function(\s+([^\(\s]+))?.*?\)\s*\{)/mg
while (matches = regex.exec(myval)) {
    document.writeln(matches[1]) //function definition
    if (matches[2])
         document.writeln(matches[2]) //function name
}
```

Comment: thanks, will this work if it is an anonymous function?